# Contractions - i will and it would

Tags: contractions, informal-language

Can i contract "it will" and "it would"? Seems very hard to pronounce. Event if it is possible is it widely used?

Comment: It'd be easy enough to check this on Google. Try that and it'll be obvious.

Comment: I did find out that these contractions formally exist. But i was more wondering whether they are commonly used or they are just some rare or archaic forms.

Comment: The lovely thing about Google is that you see the words you're looking up in context: you can tell whether they're only used in technical works, or only in fiction, or in casual conversation. These two are mostly casual.

Comment: It'd be a shame not to check it out. It'll be well worth it. ;)

Comment: I know contractions in general are very informal, like you say causal conversation. However i was wondering whether those two are somewhat different compared to other common contractions, since it seems like they might be okay in written english but in spoken english they seem to be much harder to pronounce than other common contractions, so i thought that it may be common practice to not use those when speaking even while using other contractions.

Comment: same as all contractions - they would be far less likely to have developed in their written form first - something had to drive it… usage in speech.

Answer (score 2):

"It'll" and "it'd" are widely used, and are easy for native speakers to pronounce. That's the point of contractions -- by leaving out sounds, you can speak faster and more smoothly.

Comment: To expand a bit: they would rhyme with *little* and *fitted* respectively, neither of which is considered a tongue-twister. The *t* in *it'll* becomes voiced (some would say it's flapped or tapped, but it's essentially just a *d* with an attitude in most mouths, and it transitions well to the *l*, which really plays the role of a vowel voicing in the terminal position).